# Iterating through array on mouseclick JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, onclick, iterator

I have this code. I click on this button and it calls this function and returns my array through promises.
Now with that array I want to iterate through by clicking either a `like` or `dislike` button and then moving to the next item in the array or rather displaying the next time. i have tried the below

```
 for (var i = 0; i < users_array.length; i++) {
   console.log(users_array[i].name);
   document.getElementById('displayUsers').innerHTML = users_array[i].name;
 }
```

but all this does it replace the innerHTML with the last name in the array. the code needs altering to allow me to control the array rather than the for loop. rest of the code is below:

```
document.getElementById('revealUser').onclick = displayDaUsers


function displayDaUsers(users_array){
  pullAllUsersFromDB().then(function(users_array){
       console.log(users_array);
  })
}

function pullAllUsersFromDB(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      rootRef.child('users').on('value', function(snapshot) {
      var users_object = snapshot.val();
      var users_array = Object.keys(users_object).map(function(key) {
        return users_object[key];
      });
      resolve(users_array)
    });
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code you with each iteration you replace innerHTML value. in order to get an array of values you can do something like this:

```
var usersList = [];
users_array.forEach(function(user){
   usersList.push(user.name)
}
document.getElementById('displayUsers').innerHTML = usersList.join(' ');
```